# Field Collection fields not showing field values in edit form

Tags: 7, entities

After creating content in Drupal 7, when i open edit form, field collection fields are shown as empty , but on the node view page, values are shown.

Comment: Are they showing empty or are you not seeing the field collection on the node content?

Comment: Fields are showing , but they are empty , no data is shown in the fields , but when i go to view page , data is displayed which was added during content creation

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I'm using Field Collections extensively in Drupal 7 and I have never experienced this. What version of Drupal core and Field Collections are you using? Are you using default values in the field at all? Maybe take a look to see if this issue matches what you're seeing: https://www.drupal.org/node/1239946